# Orthogonal invariance of a vector implies orthogonal invariance of subvector

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

My problem seems somewhat basic yet I can't seem to solve it directly. The problem is this:

> Suppose $\mathbf{x}\in \mathbb{R}^n$ is *orthogonally invariant*, i.e.,
>    $$ \mathbf{x} = \mathbf{H}\mathbf{x},\ \forall\, \mathbf{H}\in \mathbf{O}_n $$
>   where $\mathbf{O}_n = \{\mathbf{K}\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}: \mathbf{K'K}= \mathbf{KK'} = \mathbf{I}_n\}$. If $\mathbf{x} = (\mathbf{x}_1', \mathbf{x}_2')'$ is some ''partition'' of $\mathbf{x}$, show that $\mathbf{x}_1$ is also orthogonally invariant.

I attempted partitioning $\mathbf{H}$ in my direct proof but it utterly failed. I was aiming to arrive with something like $\mathbf{x}_1 = \mathbf{H}_1\mathbf{x}_1,\ \forall\, \mathbf{H}_1\in \mathbf{O}_m,\ m<n$. Any help? Preferably, I am looking for a non-abstract algebra solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that the partition includes the first $m$ coordinates, i.e. using the splitting $\mathbb R^n=\mathbb R^m\times \mathbb R^{n-m}$. Then every $O_m$ can be embedded into an $O_n$ by forming the block diagonal matrix
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
O_m&0\\0&I_{n-m}
\end{pmatrix}
$$
which is easily seen to be orthogonal. Since this matrix acts like $O_m$ on the first $m$ coordinates and it is the identity on the last $n-m$ coordinates, it follows that $x_1$ is orthogonally invariant.

Comment: pre-kidney, I get your point and it is very intuitive. My follow-up question to this is, "Can you point out some reference (link, book, article, etc.) that defines 'orthogonal invariance' this way?"

Comment: It is a special case of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariant_(mathematics)#Unchanged_under_group_action where the group is taken to be the group of orthogonal matrices, with group operation being matrix multiplication.